# Get an exception when calling the setMod() method

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
package dsboy08.BattleX;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/**
* Created by dsboy08 on 11/23/14.
*/
public class Start {
public String enemyName;
public int playerHP;
public int enemyHP;
public int playerMinDamageHit;
public int playerMaxDamageHit;
public int enemyMinDamageHit;
public int enemyMaxDamageHit;
public int playerHealMin;
public int playerHealMax;
public void setMod(String LocalModName, String LocalEnemyName, int LocalPlayerHP, int LocalEnemyHP, int LocalPlayerMinDamageHit, int LocalPlayerMaxDamageHit, int LocalEnemyMinDamageHit, int LocalEnemyMaxDamageHit, int LocalPlayerHealMin, int LocalPlayerHealMax){
    playerHP = LocalPlayerHP;
    enemyName = LocalEnemyName;
    enemyHP = LocalEnemyHP;
    playerMinDamageHit = LocalPlayerMinDamageHit;
    playerMaxDamageHit = LocalPlayerMaxDamageHit;
    enemyMinDamageHit = LocalEnemyMinDamageHit;
    enemyMaxDamageHit = LocalEnemyMaxDamageHit;
    playerHealMin = LocalPlayerHealMin;
    playerHealMax = LocalPlayerHealMax;
    print("Welcome to BattleX! Press 1 to start and 2 to exit.");
    print("Mod: "+LocalModName+" loaded.");
    Scanner menuItem = new Scanner(System.in);
    String menuItem2 = menuItem.nextLine();
    if(menuItem2.equals("1")) {
        startGame();
    }else {
        if (menuItem2.equals("2")) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public void print(String text){
    System.out.println(text);
}

public void startGame(){
    print("Current "+enemyName+" HP: "+playerHP);
    print("Your current HP: "+enemyHP);
    print("1: Attack");
    print("2: Heal");
    Scanner battleOption = new Scanner(System.in);
    String battleOption2 = battleOption.nextLine();
    if(battleOption2.equals("1")) {
        attack();
    }else {
        if (battleOption2.equals("2")) {
            heal();
        }else{
            startGame();
        }
    }
}

public void attack(){
    Random humanAttack = new Random();
    int attackDamage = humanAttack.nextInt((playerMinDamageHit - playerMaxDamageHit) + 1) + playerMinDamageHit;
    print("Attacking for " + attackDamage + " damage.");
    enemyHP = enemyHP - attackDamage;
    int bearAttackDamage = humanAttack.nextInt((enemyMinDamageHit - enemyMaxDamageHit) + 1) + enemyMinDamageHit;
    print("The "+enemyName+" attacked for "+bearAttackDamage+" damage.");
    playerHP = playerHP - bearAttackDamage;
    if(playerHP <= 0){
        print("You failed! The "+enemyName+" killed you ;)");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if(enemyHP <= 0){
        print("You defeated the "+enemyName+"! Good job!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    startGame();
}

public void heal(){
    Random healAmount = new Random();
    int randomHealAmount = healAmount.nextInt((playerHealMin - playerHealMin) + 1) + playerHealMin;
    int bearAttackDamage = healAmount.nextInt((enemyMinDamageHit - enemyMaxDamageHit) + 1) + enemyMinDamageHit;
    playerHP = playerHP + randomHealAmount;
    if(playerHP + randomHealAmount >= 100){
        playerHP = 100;
    }
    playerHP = playerHP - bearAttackDamage;
    print("You have healed "+randomHealAmount+" health, but you have also lost "+bearAttackDamage+" health.");
    if(playerHP <= 0){
        print("You failed! The "+enemyName+" killed you ;)");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if(enemyHP <= 0){
        print("You defeated the "+enemyName+"! Good job!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    startGame();
}
}
```

Here is my "main" code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    new dsboy08.BattleX.Start().setMod("ExampleMod", "Death", 100, 50, 5, 10, 5, 15, 3, 10);
}
```

I get a exception from (what seems to be a static context, but I cant seem to fix it).

Here is my exception call:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
at dsboy08.BattleX.Start.attack(Start.java:67)
at dsboy08.BattleX.Start.startGame(Start.java:55)
at dsboy08.BattleX.Start.setMod(Start.java:33)
at dsboy08.BattleX.ModStart.main(ModStart.java:8)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I tried to fix it by making the methods not static, but it doesnt really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What will happen here:

```
humanAttack.nextInt((enemyMinDamageHit - enemyMaxDamageHit) + 1)
```

if the parameter to the `.nextInt(...)` method is negative?  You'll get an exception, is what. Since Max is > than Min, so this is likely. You'd best make sure that the parameters are in fact positive.

Myself, I'd swap them, by changing

```
humanAttack.nextInt((enemyMinDamageHit - enemyMaxDamageHit) + 1)
```

to

```
humanAttack.nextInt((enemyMaxDamageHit - enemyMinDamageHit) + 1)
```

---

---

Most importantly, you will want to read all exception messages critically since the information that they pass to you is not gibberish, but rather often (and in your case precisely) tells you what is wrong and where.

Your exception message tells you:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
```

So you know that some number **used as a method or constructor parameter** is negative but should in fact be positive.

```
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
```

OK, it involves something to do with a Random object's `nextInt(...)` call.

```
at dsboy08.BattleX.Start.attack(Start.java:67)
```

and the problem is at line 67 of the Start class, in the attack method.